# how to save login details of android app?

Tags: android, authentication

I have a android application which needs username and password to login. I need to save the username and password locally in phone or somewhere to use them when the user opens the app next time and  logins to the app automatically without showing the login screen

```
    EditText input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usertext);
    EditText input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Passtext);
    String username = input1.getText().toString();
    String password = input2.getText().toString();
```

If the login is successful, it will call the activity through intent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using ApiLevel >= 5 read about [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html).

Comment: Nice, didn't know it existed :)

Comment: As per Android documentation
"It's important to understand that AccountManager is not an encryption service or a keychain. **It stores account credentials just as you pass them, in plain text.** On most devices, this isn't a particular concern, because it stores them in a database that is only accessible to root. But on a rooted device, the credentials would be readable by anyone with adb access to the device"

It is equivalent to storing password in plain text in private SharedPreference, I wld suggest use any key to generate md5 & then store it in private SharedPreference or AccountManager.

Answer (score 3):

I would recomend to use something like MD5 or SHA1 for hashing your password before storing.

A possible place to store could either be "preferences" or the sqlite DB (not such usefull for only one single dataset)

Answer (score 2):

To save username & password in sharepref try

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=mPreferences.edit();
private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CurrentUser", MODE_PRIVATE);
editor.putString("UserName", username);
editor.putString("PassWord", password);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: This is a very bad idea, since this can be accessed by anyone having root privileges (quite easy to obtain nowadays).

Answer (score 0):

You can use preferences or a file if you don't really care about security. You should encrypt the password if you're gonna store them though.
See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for a better description of the options.