# Best Practices on Storing Login Info on Android

Tags: android, security, authentication, encryption

I'm kinda of a noob at Android and I'm writing a simple app, for my own personal learning, to hookup to an external API (Flickr or Netflix).  What I want to do is ask the user for their login info to either site so that they can view their pictures or dvd queue.  My question is what's the best practice to store user data like that?

I was thinking of encrypting the login/pwd and store it onto the SD card.  Any thoughts using this method? Is there a better method?

I'm interested in reading other developer's perspective.

I'm sure there are numerous methods out there.  I just don't want break "#1 Rule" of storing user info.

Thanks.

Comment: possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085371/how-to-save-login-details-of-android-app

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085371/how-to-save-login-details-of-android-app):

> If you are using ApiLevel >= 5 read
>   about [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html).

The [SampleSyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html) tutorial uses AccountManager. It might be a good place to start.